# overly reacting vs. overreacting

Tags: grammar

1. You are overly reacting.
2. You are overreacting.

Do the two sentences mean exactly the same thing? If so, could you please explain why native speakers use the second one way more often than the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should almost certainly say "overreacting"

The word "overreact" is a compound verb and it's meaning can't be completely understood from the parts "over+react" It means "act too intensely as a direct result of something else

"Overly" is an adverb that is mostly used to modify adjectives, it means "too"

> This is overly optimistic.

*We rarely use overly to modify a verb.*

So you should say "She is overreacting" (in the present continuous) or you should say "Her reaction was overly intense" (or similar). You don't say "overly reacting"

Answer (score 1):

> You are overly reacting.

I would say the above  has no clear meaning.  In the sentence

> You are reacting.

the word "reacting" is, in traditional terms, a gerund, because it functions as a noun. Therefore it may no be modifies by an adverb, only by an adjective. "overly " is an adverb, so it does not make sense in this construction. "Over" is an adjective (or it can be) so it works here. The resulting sentence

> You are over reacting.

has become

> You are overreacting.

Because "over" is a particular;ly common modifier for this and several other gerunds, forming such words as "overthinking", "overdoing", and "overachieving".

Comment: "You are reacting" looks like the present continuous to me, not a gerund complement. Compare "You are quickly running" which is acceptable, if slightly odd.